# JS - get filename with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the extension and name of a file using Ajax.

My ajax code looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $("#updateMember").serialize(), 
    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

In PHP I have this

```
$imageFileType = pathinfo($_FILES["input9"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
echo $imageFileType;
```

and my html is

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="updateMember">
    <input id="input-9" name="input9" type="file" class="file file-loading" data-allowed-file-extensions='["png", "jpg", "gif", "jpeg"]' style="top: 0px;">
    <li class="menu__item"><input name="offerUpload" id="dashOffersBtn" class="menu__link menu_input btnDashboard" style="margin: 0 auto; height:20px;padding: 0;padding-bottom: 22px;width: 70%;" type="button" value="SAVE"></li>
</form>
```

but it seems to not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "*but it seems to not work*" Which begs the question: *What* does not work?

Comment: What  error you get?

Comment: I don't get any error, the file name seems to be empty

Comment: However if I do the same without using Ajax this works

Comment: @SNos $("#updateMember").serialize() is a problem , you have to use FormData();

Comment: Thanks Arsh. I will try it.

Comment: Cool , try it , 99% it should work.

Comment: I am trying using it like `var fd = new FormData();
                fd.append('file', $("#input-9").files[0]);` but I get that files is not an object

Comment: @Snos You can target the whole form with FormData();  var fd = new FormData('#updateMember');

Comment: @SNos i did ad it as answer with the code , try that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `FormData()` to make this possible, serialize or serializeArray() does not support file api's use the below solution :

**Main update for working solution**

I did update the Save button's type from button to submit please use the below html :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="updateMember">
    <input id="input-9" name="input9" type="file" class="file file-loading" data-allowed-file-extensions='["png", "jpg", "gif", "jpeg"]' style="top: 0px;">
    <li class="menu__item">
    <input name="offerUpload" id="dashOffersBtn" class="menu__link menu_input btnDashboard" style="margin: 0 auto; height:20px;padding: 0;padding-bottom: 22px;width: 70%;" type="submit" value="SAVE">
    </li>
</form>
```

and use the below jquery code to make it work

```
jQuery('#updateMember').submit(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
            var data = new FormData(this);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'upload.php',
                    data: data, 
                    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "html",
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
        });
```

also use the below php code for extension :

```
$data = $_FILES['input9'];
$data_ext = explode('/',$data['type']);
$extension = $data_ext[1];
echo $extension;
```

My test index.php code

**http://pastebin.com/L81xUbxL**

Change `Url` To your target url.

**Old non working**

```
 var data = new FormData('#updateMember');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data, 
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

for getting an extension you can do this

```
$path_ = pathinfo($_FILES["input9"]["name"]);
$extension = $path_['extension'];
echo $extension;
```

Comment: Thanks still get an empty alert.I cannot get the file extension

Comment: something I do is wrong.. still getting an empty alert

Comment: even If i echo path_ I get nothing

Comment: do a var_dump($path_); and tell me what you get

Comment: I get ------   `array(2) {
  ["basename"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["filename"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
`

Comment: @SNos hey wait 2 min , let me try your code and get back to you just 2 mins

Comment: @SNos Hey , i have rewamped the code for you , let me just put it in my answer including the html and javascript code

Comment: @SNos do check my answer. Check the part after tagline :Main update for working solution

Comment: @SNos i'm also adding the php part for extension , old one will not work

Comment: now I get `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this[0].form')`

Comment: @SNos , that is not related to my code , did you replace the whole jquery code with mine ? it does not seem that you have used my jquery code , for me it's working without any problem.

Comment: @SNos , i have pasted my index.php 's full code for you to take a look at and see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Thank you so muchhhh.. I had your code inside `$(document).ready(function` .. It is working very good now

Comment: @SNos you are welcome. always try to dump the arrays to check what they are providing to you.

Comment: Yes I will do it. Now I have to find the way to add the rest of my code to it.. But this was so helpful

Comment: @SNos don't worry , you will do it (Y) , it's pretty much easy.